# Mapping memory mentioned in BAR when you have less memory available

Tags: linux, pci

I am writing a driver for PCIe network device. I am still trying to learn, so my question might be like a simple one as I do not understand most of the things.

From the BAR0 address that I read, the memory size is around 256MB. But I have only 128MB at my disposal.

So my question is how do i map this BAR so as to access the MMIO region.

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A device that is memory-mapped simply responds to memory addresses.  It does not occupy any physical RAM in the system.  Typically memory-mapped devices are assigned to a memory address that does not overlap with physical memory.

Your typical x86 processor has a 32-bit address space (0x00000000-0xFFFFFFFF).  If you have 128MB of RAM, that occupies physical addresses from 0x00000000-0x08000000 (roughly).  That leave a lot of room above 0x08000000 for PCI devices.

Look at the addresses of your PCI device BARs.  They are probably all values somewhere in the upper half of your address space (0x80000000 or higher).